# Check if scrollbar reached a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check when a div is reached from scrollbar with jquery.
I read some similar question on stackoverflow, but all are on one div only.
I have 4 div, with height: 100% and I want know when the scroll bar pass every div.
I tried, but only works with the first div.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="service"></div>
<div id="clients"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#main {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}
#service {
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
}
#clients {
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
}
#about {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var passed_service = false;
    var passed_service = false;
    $('body,html').bind('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(event){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= ($("#service").height())){
            if(!passed_service){
                alert("To #service");
                passed_service = true;
            }
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= ($("#service").height() + $("#clients").height())){
            if(!passed_clients){
                alert("To #clients");
                passed_clients = true;
            }
        } 
    });
});
```

SORRY TO ALL, WAS A MY STUPID ERROR, I CAN'T DELETE THE QUESTION :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var passed_service = false;
var passed_service = false; /* should be 'passed_clients' */
```

^ There's your problem

---

Also, instead of adding up the divs' heights, use the top offset instead.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/gq8zv/)

```
$(window).scrollTop() >= $("#service").offset().top
$(window).scrollTop() >= $("#clients").offset().top
...
```

Comment: My fault on jsfiddle, but not is this the problem but something here:
`code`
if($(window).scrollTop() >= ($("#service").height() + $("#clients").height())){

Answer (score 0):

You never declare the `passed_clients` variable.

Change this:

```
var passed_service = false;
var passed_service = false;
```

to this:

```
var passed_service = false;
var passed_clients = false;
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XUEfD/8/

Answer (score 0):

Working [Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/XUEfD/13/)

```
use this: (parseInt($("#service").height()) + parseInt($("#clients").height()))

$(document).ready(function() {
var passed_service = false;
var passed_clients = false;
$('body,html').bind('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(event){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= ($("#service").height())){
        if(!passed_service){
            alert("To #service");
            passed_service = true;
        }
    }

    //console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= (parseInt($("#service").height()) + parseInt($("#clients").height()))){
        if(!passed_clients){
            alert("To #clients");
            passed_clients = true;
        }
    } 
});
});
```